# SSIS: failed to mark the cache as filled with data

Tags: ssis, etl

I'm creating an Integration Services package in Visual Studio 2010 Shell. I have a lookup transformation in the package that was working fine until recently.

About two weeks ago, the lookup transformation started failing. It will process about 1800 rows and then crash (the number of rows processed before crashing varies with each run. The error I receive is listed below:

Error: 0xC0010202 at Check if source key exists in bridge table, Lookup 1 [746]: Failed to mark the cache as filled with data.

One of the things that I find perplexing is that I receive this message regardless of whether I use full, partial, or no cache. I'm confused as to why the lookup would try to mark the cache as filled even when i set the lookup to not use a cache.

I've googled this and tried to adjust every setting and advanced setting that I could get my hands on but to no avail. Has anyone else had any experience like this?

Comment: for the error message, have you ever checked whether the column need to matches from the destination table exists or not, and if that does not work, try to delete the `lookup` transformation and create it again

Comment: @LONG Rows with no matching entries are redirected to the no match output so that shouldn't be an issue. I tried recreating the lookup from scratch yesterday but I received the same error message.

Comment: I did not mean the unmatched records, what I mean is you probably have changed (deleted or updated) the destination column name or the column does not exist, but the previous `lookup`still cache the destination column name, that's why I suggest you to delete the `lookup` and create a new `lookup` to see whether the problem remains or not

Comment: @LONG Ah, I understand what you mean now. The column hasn't changed though. The lookup works for a while - I think it would fail right from the start if the column was missing or renamed.

Comment: Correct ;) Give it a try

Comment: Derek, if @LONG's suggestion did not work, do you mind sharing the any other error messages associated with this? If the lookup starts filling the rows and bails out mid way, I would check if there are any issues with the query supplying the lookup data. Is it stuck on sql server?

Comment: I just deleted the lookup and added it but I'm getting the same error. @SamKolli here are the other error messages:

Comment: Error: 0xC004701A at Check if source key exists in bridge table, SSIS.Pipeline: Fuzzy Lookup failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x8007007A.

Comment: Error: 0xC004701B at Check if source key exists in bridge table, SSIS.Pipeline: Lookup failed the cleanup phase and returned error code 0xC0010202.

Comment: Sorry Derek, not getting much out of the rest of the error messages.